# Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

```
package com.luv3code.testdb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestDBServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/TestDbServlet")
public class TestDBServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String user="springstudent";
        String pass="springstudent";
        String jdbcUrl= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL&serverTimezome=UTC";

        String driver= "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";

        try {
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.println("Connect to Database: " +jdbcUrl);
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection myConn= DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, pass);
            out.println("suceess");

        }catch(Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException(exc);
        }
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

}
```

I create a connection springstudent: with user spring student. Besides create a database with table on my workbench.

I would like to connect my eclipse project on my database. So I write the code and add a library.

My steps:

1. Download apache tomcat

   Create web-dynamic project. Create a servlet  Add library
   my-sql-8.0.12

   Java compiler, Java built path, Project Facest have the same version

   I try to run doing both of the above settings:  Server Right Click
   priorities : workspace metadata  Server Right Click priorities :
   local

   Delete and add the server(Window->Show Servers...)  Check project
   facets->runtime apache clicked Clean project Clean server

   Delete and import project again.

   console:

> Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.35 Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   built:          May 5 2020 20:36:20 UTC Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   version number: 9.0.35.0 Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS Name:
>   Windows 10 Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS
>   Version:            10.0 Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   Architecture:          amd64 Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Java Home:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Version:           1.8.0_251-b08 Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Vendor:            Oracle Corporation Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   CATALINA_BASE:
>   C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
>   Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 9.0 Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument:
>   -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
>   Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 9.0 Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument:
>   -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
>   Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1253 Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO:
>   Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.24] using APR version
>   [1.7.0]. Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO: APR
>   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
>   random [true]. Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO:
>   APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
>   Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:58 ΠΜ org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   initializeSSL INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1g 
>   21 Apr 2020] Ιουν 14, 2020 1:57:59 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"] Ιουν 14, 2020 1:58:00 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Server initialization
>   in [2,379] milliseconds Ιουν 14, 2020 1:58:00 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service [Catalina] Ιουν 14, 2020 1:58:00 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35] Ιουν 14, 2020 1:58:02 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars INFO: At least one JAR
>   was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for
>   this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs
>   were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time. Ιουν 14, 2020 1:58:03 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"] Ιουν 14, 2020 1:58:03 ΠΜ
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   [2,449] milliseconds
>
> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message The requested resource [/web-customer-tracker/] is not
>   available
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

I have two PC, in the first one run the program if change 
@WebServlet("/") I cannot undresand why.
In this it doesn't run.

I also reinstall eclipse and tomcat.
Eclipse 2019 
Apache 9
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)

Could someone help me?

Comment: Simply right-click on your servlet and choose `Run As > Run on Server`.

Comment: Ohhh..I cannot believe that dedicate so time, only because run my folder!! 
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Copied my comment to answer so that it can be more visible and help future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply right-click on your servlet and choose `Run As > Run on Server`.